# How i can dispatch one list in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this class that shows a list of cars:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>

            {this.props.cars.map((car) => <Car key={car.Id} car={car} />)}

        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm making a http request to get the cars in my api:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/cars`)
          .then(res => {
            const cars= res.data.records;
            this.props.dispatch({
                type:'GET_CARS',
            cars});
          })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListCars);
```

How i can make a reducer that add to props.cars the return of axios get? my actually reducer is don't working:

```
const CarReducer= (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_CAR':
        return state.concat([action.data]);
      case 'GET_CARS':
        return state.map(car =>
          car
        )
      default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default carReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

You dispatched this plain object to Redux:

```
this.props.dispatch({ type:'GET_CARS', cars })
```

So, you will be able to receive your data from `action.cars` in your reducer and add it to your Redux store:

```
const CarReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CAR':
            return state.concat([action.data]);

        case 'GET_CARS':

            // Receive data from action.cars
            // I am assuming your data is in an array
            return [...state, ...action.cars];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then, in your component, you should be able to receive the data from the API by using `connect()` from `react-redux`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.cars.map((car) => 
                    <Car key={car.Id} car={car} />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { cars: state.cars }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```